# DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future. While broadcasting large arrays

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to compare each element of one array to each element in another one. The arrays are fairly large -

```py
arr1.shape = (59913, )

arr2.shape = (988114, )
```

To do this comparison, I use the following code:

```
A = np.array(arr1[:])[:, np.newaxis] == np.array(arr1[:])[np.newaxis, :]
np.sum(A)
```

The strange thing is that when i limit the length of either of `arr1` or `arr2` - everything works as expected and i get a NxN boolean matrix as A, but when I try to run it for the full arrays - i get the following warning -

> **DeprecationWarning:**  elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

and a single output: **False**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather late, but I just encountered the same error and I found out that it is due to lack of memory.

`res = np.where(~((a[:, None] == b).all(-1).any(-1)))`

`a.shape = (14731, 128) b.shape = (3725, 128)`

main__:5: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

That's what I got. By reducing the size of b gradually, I realized that at some point starts working properly.
So, I think it is a matter of memory lack and the message displayed is rather misleading.
My goal was to keep rows of a that are not present in b. Found a solution using pandas.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference. Thanks.