# np.meshgrid throws DeprecationWarning or MemoryError for large inputs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a clustering problem I am trying to create the ideal similarity matrix. That is, I have an one-dimensional array of cluster labels and need to create a two-dimensional binary or boolean matrix with an entry of 1 iff two data points belong to the same cluster.

To do so I use `np.meshgrid` but it only works for smaller examples. Here's an MWE:

**With an array of size 5 it works as desired:**

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=5)
print(arr)
mesh_grid = np.meshgrid(arr, arr, sparse=True)
mesh_grid[0] == mesh_grid[1]
```

gives

```
[9 0 9 0 7]
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

**However, with an array of size 60000 it does not work:**

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=60000)
mesh_grid = np.meshgrid(arr, arr, sparse=True)
mesh_grid[0] == mesh_grid[1]
```

gives

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  mesh_grid[0] == mesh_grid[1]
```

Setting `sparse=False` throws a memory error. And based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653220/12268505) I assume the `DeprecationWarning`must be due to memory too.

**Question**: How can I solve this or is there another more efficient way to obtain the desired matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, your array is composed by only 10 differents element (0,1,2,3....) then you only need to compare your array with those 10 elements and not with the whole matrix.

So you can do the following operations:

```
# Number of different elements
n = 3
# Generate the random vector (2D)
arr = np.random.randint(0, n, size=10)[None,:]
# Create the vector containing all the different elements (2D)
num = np.r_[0:n][:,None]
# We broadcast the 2 vectors to obtain a n*10 matrix
uni = arr==num
# Based on the previous result, we duplicate the row that need to be duplicated:
res = uni[arr] # 10 * 10 matrix
```

You can use `np.unique()` to extract the unique values of `arr` in the case where your unique value are not linearly distributed.